# How to round a number with a data type float?

Tags: sapui5

Pretty direct question. I'm looking to take an outputted number, and round it to 2 decimal places. It appears that I'm only able to truncate a number using `maxFractionDigits` (see code below)

**How can I round a number to 2 decimal places?**

```
<Input
    value="{
        path: 'helloPanel>/recipient/amount',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Float',
        formatOptions: {
            minFractionDigits: 2,
            maxFractionDigits: 2
        }
    }"
    description="Hello {helloPanel>/recipient/name}"
    valueLiveUpdate="false"
    width="60%"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve rounding easily by defining a specific [rounding mode](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.RoundingMode) in the section `/formatOptions/roundingMode`.

Typically, the rounding mode is `HALF_AWAY_FROM_ZERO` by default. E.g. if the real value is `1.678`, the output will be `1.68` (assuming `maxFractionDigits: 2`). However, if the real value is `1.671`, the output will be `1.67` because `HALF_*` rounds always from `5` and upwards.

If you want the framework to round always *away from zero* (regardless whether the next digit of `maxFractionDigits` is higher than 4 or not), then your code would look like this:

```xml
<Input xmlns="sap.m"
  value="{
    path: 'helloPanel>/recipient/amount',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Float',
    formatOptions: {
      maxFractionDigits: 2,
      roundingMode: 'AWAY_FROM_ZERO'
    }
  }"
/>
```

**⚠️ Note**: if the target SAPUI5/OpenUI5 version is lower than 1.85, assign the rounding mode string all in lowercase (`AWAY_FROM_ZERO` → `away_from_zero`). Otherwise, there will be a vague TypeError. This bug is fixed since 1.85: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2169

---

## Rounding Modes

Here are some graphics showing the differences between the rounding modes.
See also the [table in the section "Miscellaneous" of the topic "Number Format"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f2f2866f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070).

### `roundingMode: 'AWAY_FROM_ZERO'`

±1.678 → ±1.68

[image: UI5 rounding mode - AWAY_FROM_ZERO]

### `roundingMode: 'TOWARDS_ZERO'`

±1.678 → ±1.67

[image: UI5 rounding mode - TOWARDS_ZERO]

### `roundingMode: 'FLOOR'`

"Towards negative infinity": -1.678 → -1.68 || 1.678 → 1.67

[image: UI5 rounding mode - FLOOR]

### `roundingMode: 'CEILING'`

"Towards positive infinity": -1.678 → -1.67 || 1.678 → 1.68

[image: UI5 rounding mode - CEILING]

### `roundingMode: 'HALF_...'`

One of the four rounding modes but only starting from 5+.
E.g. `roundingMode: 'HALF_CEILING'`: -1.678 → -1.67 || 1.67**4** → 1.67 even if the mode was *CEILING*.

---

According to the [`NumberFormat` reference](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat), there is also a possibility to define your own mutator by assigning a function.

> ... [Rounding mode] can be assigned:
>
> - by value in [`RoundingMode`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.RoundingMode),
> - via a **function** that is used for rounding the number and takes two parameters: the number itself, and the number of decimal digits that should be reserved. *

* Deprecated since UI5 1.121.